# vue.js routing issue in apache

Tags: apache, vue-router

I have a vue.js application with vue router to render various components. I have a path `/home` which loads the home component. In the dev environment, I was able to go to the component by giving `localhost:8080/home` in my address bar and also by setting links using `<router-link>`. When I deploy the production build to apache server, when I give `localhost/home` is giving the error

> The requested URL /home was not found on this server.

But the links are working and `localhost/home` is shown in the address bar when we click on the link
Why this happens? How to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the router instance, I used history mode which gives a URL without hash(#). I changed the mode form 'history' to the default 'hash' and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate your solution a bit more?

Answer (score 5):

Directly from the Vue router web site.

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to
>   simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL
>   changes.
>
> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which
>   leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without
>   a page reload:
>
> const router = new VueRouter({   mode: 'history',   routes: [...] })
>   When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g.
>   http://oursite.com/user/id. Beautiful!
>
> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client
>   side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a
>   404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their
>   browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple
>   catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any
>   static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app
>   lives in. Beautiful, again!
>
> Apache
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> nginx
>
> ```
> location / {
>   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
> }
> ```
>
> Native Node.js
>
> ```
> const http = require('http')
> const fs = require('fs')
> const httpPort = 80
>
> http.createServer((req, res) => {
>   fs.readFile('index.htm', 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
>     if (err) {
>       console.log('We cannot open "index.htm" file.')
>     }
>
>     res.writeHead(200, {
>       'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>     })
>
>     res.end(content)
>   })
> }).listen(httpPort, () => {
>   console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:%s', httpPort)
> })
> ```

[0] https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html